# Adding Polly Retry policy globally

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I know you can register an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` to a particular instance of an `HttpClient` injected into a service, but is there a way to configure this globally, to all HttpClients wired up via microsofts dependency injection?

For example, you can wire up the HttpClient injected into `MyService` via:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyService>(
    .AddPolicyHandler(
        HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt =>
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))));
```

But I would like to add this policy handler to all HttpClients. The class that I would like to add retries to is 3rd party and marked as internal, so I cannot directly access it.

Comment: You can't because there's no way to determine how each client is created. But it sounds like you might be asking the wrong question. Do you need a way to add retries globally or do you really just need a way to add them to that third party library?

Answer (score 1):

**In short**: With a custom HttpClientFactory you can but should not aim for this.

[In order to use retry](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#retry-) against an endpoint all these prerequisites should be met:

- The potentially introduced observable impact is acceptable
- The operation can be redone without any irreversible side effect
- The introduced complexity is negligible compared to the promised reliability

If we are talking about a REST API then implementing all CRUD operations in an idempotent is feasible but quite challenging to do it in a right way. So, most of the time you want to apply retry logic against **only your retrieve calls**, not against your data manipulation calls.

Also be aware that retries can make things even worse. If the downstream system is overloaded then sending new requests will not help the self-healing. Most probably it needs some "air" to go back to normal state from degraded. That's where [Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#circuit-breaker-) might be helpful to avoid flooding downstream systems when it is already having hard time.

You can combine Retry and Circuit Breaker policies via [escalation](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#escalation-)

- where CB is the inner policy
- and Retry is the outer.

Comment: That resiliency write-up is gold.  Well written and clearly explained.  Fantastic job with it!